# Java 8 Modify Fields with reflections

Tags: java

I have have a problem with this field:

```
private final String name = "test";
```

I want to modify it with reflections, but it doesn't work.

```
Field field = Test.class.getDeclaredField("name");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(OBJECT, "Paul");
```

But after this code,... the field is the same.

If I create the field with the following code:

```
private final String name;
    
public Test() {
   name = "test";
}
```

It will work..., but not with the first code :(
Is there a way to do it with the example below?
Any help?

Comment: The thing is that it actually works for both cases (try to read that field but also *via reflection* and you should see modified value). Problem with first case is that `private final String name = "test";` represents compile-time constant expression which is known at compilation time, so when compiler sees code like `System.out.println(name);` it will generate bytecode representing `System.out.println("test");` because it assumes that `name` will always be `"test"`. So even when you change later value of `name` it will not affect `System.out.println("test");`

Comment: Is there a way to do it with the example below?

Comment: Value of *constant variable* can be inlined if it is compilation-time constant (like String *literal*, primitive type *literal*, or result of their addition/concatenation, like `private String constant = "foo"+1;`). But if you initialize such constant variable with resul of something which needs to be *executed* at runtime (like result of method or constructor) which may involve things which compiler isn't aware of (like reading data from file) then compiler will not be able to know/be sure what value it will be.

Comment: So something like `private final String name = someMethod();` or `private final Stirng name = new String("abc");` will not let `name` to be inlined.